# Signs of GPU failling?

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, freeze, gpu

since a week I have been experiencing some issues that make my computer borderline unusable at times.

GPU in question: Nvidia GTX 770 2 GB. OS is Windows 10.

Description of what is happening:

1. Normal Windows boot up.
2. Opening windows sometimes no issue, sometimes the window frame becomes completely black for a second or two, then loads normally.
3. Any GPU-related tasks demonstrate behaviour in point 2. For example, GPU-accelerated Google maps. Netflix.
4. Loading games just freezes video already in the menu (not sure if computer freezes, but since video freezes becomes unresponsive).
5. Sometimes just normal browsing creates issues as described in point 2.
6. At times the whole screen goes black, not just a window frame. After that goes back to normal. But sometimes does not and requires a hard reset!
7. Couple of times BSOD with Video Scheduler Internal Error.

Troubleshooting I have done:

1. Reinstalled drivers - no change.
2. Disable Chrome GPU acceleration seems to alleviate the issue somewhat - e.g. doesn't freeze on google maps.
3. Installed Ubuntu and it seeems to be the same, maybe a little bit less pronounced.

I have not tried to reinstall Windows yet.
Do these signs indicate GPU failure?

Answer (score 0):

If there also are graphical artifacts - those are definitely signs of your gpu dying. Whenever you get high gpu usage or just keep it for long enough it stops working. Usually graphics card live for 5-6 years. And your gpu i assume fits in this range. You can try to google for "gpu baking", but i strongly recommend you to be extremely careful if you decide to try it. A year ago it kept my gpu alive for 5 more months (i used clothes iron) until there was no other way but to replace it.